# Get colors in less command with ccze: Shift + g doesn't go to the end of file?

Tags: colors, less

In all the tools to get colors with `less` command: `-R`, [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/), [GNU Source-highlight](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/), [vless](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/07/14/use-vim-as-a-syntax-highlighting-pager/), ... [ccze](http://blog.uggy.org/post/2005/02/24/8-ccze-un-outil-pour-mettre-un-peu-de-couleur-dans-les-logs) make me sastified with below command:

```
ccze -A < /path/to/log/file | less -R
```

but <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> doesn't work as expected:

- I must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> first
- follow by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>, but it doesn't go to the end
  of file

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see similar behavior as you describe when I try this on `/var/log/syslog` which is `2.1MB` in size and around `22500` lines long. Suspecting that `ccze` was partly to blame for it, I ran:

```
time ccze -A /var/log/syslog > foo
```

Which showed that `ccze` takes around 55 seconds on my `1.2GHz` machine to generate the colorized output. I expect this is what makes `less` hang, `less` cannot go to the end of the output before `ccze` has finished generating it, so `less` seems to hang.

Alternatives to make this work better:

- Select output with `grep`, `sed` etc. and then pipe into `ccze`.
- Pre-colorize file and run `less` on that.

Comment: Is there any tool to pre-colorize the log file?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `ccze -A LOG > SOME_FILE`. Perhaps executed in a cron job.

Comment: What do you need it for, does it have to output ANSI sequences? I usually use `vim` for log viewing, it has good syntax highlighting. Just tested it on a `7 MB` log file with no noticable lag.

Comment: `:se ft=sql` doesn't make me happy when viewing `/var/log/mysqld.log`.

Comment: I don't have mysql running anywhere, could you post a representative log excerpt? I've been playing around with syntax files lately, I might be able to cook something up.

Comment: Sure, here for you: http://fpaste.org/FJ2F/

Comment: Here is an adapted `syntax/messages.vim`, pretty simple `syn match` only. Fetch it [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17110900/mysqllog.vim), put it into `~/.vim/syntax` and run `:set ft=mysqllog`.

Answer (score 0):

Both Meta-> and Meta-< work perfectly fine for me. I'm used to them because they do the same in emacs